# Android app development on VM

Tags: android, vmware, virtual-machine

I've some experience in programming C, C++, JAVA and now I want to learn developing app for Android. But I dont have an Android device and also no in the mood for buying one. So, how can I develop app for an Android device ?

I've tried to create VM with some image but it halts on `kernel panic`
I also think that VM will be better than emulator so please help on setting a Android device out of my PC.

*I'm really new to Android !*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Eclipse and the Android SDK. It comes with an Android device emulator, so you won't actually need to buy an Android device. I've tried developing on the emulator, and the results I got were identical to what I got from my Android device. However, I would suggest that if you're going to do serious Android development, go buy an Android device, even a cheap one will do. It will make your life much easier, as the emulator that comes with the SDK is really slow. Also, having a physical Android device will be very beneficial for testing purposes. You can't really test very well with an emulator (depending on your app).

Anyway, you would go get and install Eclipse on you computer, then go [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to get the SDK for your platform. It's available for Linux, Mac, and Windows.

Also, follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html) tutorial. It will take you through all the things you need to install and will show you how to make your first application for Android. I used it when I was learning the basics, and it's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have found: [Virtualbox Virtual Machine with Eclipse and Android SDK 1.5 r2 Preinstalled](http://hartvig.de/2009/virtualbox-virtual-machine-with-eclipse-and-android-sdk-15-r2-preinstalled/). I am yet to verify it, but it claims to be a virtualbox image specifically for the development of android applications in eclipse. its quite old (2009 i think) so the sdk will be outdated, but i hope that updating will be simple. i hate faffing with IDEs and SDKs more than anything.

Edit: I can verify that it is exactly as described on the website, and works well